# Xamarin Android image Capture by Camera using intent ActionImageCapture, the image quality is low

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.android, mobile-application

Im new to Xamarin Android. Now I was trying to capture the image by camera and displaying in imageview but I was facing the problem which is the image quality that captured from camera is low. And I was doing the research from google and i only found the solution which is save the image that captured in to file and retrieve from file. But the solution is only for android studio and xamarin form.

This is the coding for the intent that calling image captured

```
Intent intent = new Intent(MediaStore.ActionImageCapture);
 StartActivityForResult(intent, 1000);
```

This is the coding for onactivityresult,

```
if ((requestCode == PickImageId) && (resultCode == Android.App.Result.Ok) && (data != null))
{
                base.OnActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
                bitmap = (Bitmap)data.Extras.Get("data");                             
                var dir = Android.OS.Environment.GetExternalStoragePublicDirectory(Android.OS.Environment.DirectoryDcim);
                string filename = System.DateTime.Now.ToString("yyyyMMddHHmmssfff") + ".jpg";
                string filePath = System.IO.Path.Combine(dir + "/Camera/", filename);
                using (var stream = new MemoryStream())
                {
                    bitmap.Compress(Bitmap.CompressFormat.Jpeg, 100, stream);
                    byte[] bitmapData = stream.ToArray();
                    try
                    {
                        System.IO.File.WriteAllBytes(filePath, bitmapData);
                        bitmap = BitmapFactory.DecodeByteArray(bitmapData, 0, bitmapData.Length);
                        imgview.SetImageBitmap(bitmap);
                    }
                    catch (Exception ex)
                    {
                        System.Console.WriteLine(ex.ToString());
                    }
                }               
}
```

I have try to save the image into phone folder which is 'DCIM/Camera/xxx.jpg'. The image that captured and save in folder is success but the image quality still low.
Is there have any solution to increase the quality of the image?
Sorry for my poor english, please provide me suggestion or solution.
Thanks for giving helps

Answer (score 0):

Hello you can use Xamarin Essential Media Picker to take photo.
Here is an example code:

```
   using Xamarin.Essentials;
   string PhotoPath="";

   public async Task TakePhotoAsync()
    {
        try
        {
            var photo = await MediaPicker.CapturePhotoAsync();
            await LoadPhotoAsync(photo);
        }
        catch (FeatureNotSupportedException fnsEx)
        {
            // Feature is not supported on the device
        }
        catch (PermissionException pEx)
        {
            // Permissions not granted
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Console.WriteLine($"CapturePhotoAsync THREW: {ex.Message}");
        }
    }


    public async Task LoadPhotoAsync(FileResult photo)
    {
        // canceled
        if (photo == null)
        {
            PhotoPath = null;
            return;
        }
        // save the file into local storage
        var newFile = Path.Combine(FileSystem.CacheDirectory, photo.FileName); //or any other Storage Directory
        using (var stream = await photo.OpenReadAsync())
        using (var newStream = File.OpenWrite(newFile))
            await stream.CopyToAsync(newStream);

        PhotoPath = newFile;
        }
```